# Custom block.tpl not affectiong all blocks

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a custom theme and in the templates folder I have copied block.tpl and changed H2 to H3 and added a CSS class to the content div. Changes are taking affect and drupal is loading my block.tpl but all blocks are not getting affected, only some. Some of the blocks which are not getting affected are Book navigation block, navigation block etc.

How do I make all blocks affected by my changes to the base block.tpl.php ?

Comment: Seems some other tpl overriding the default template file.

Comment: If I am right the book navigation block is taking html heading tag from block.tpl but not from mine.

Comment: Thats weird!!! But may be check by clearing drupal cache and where you placed the block.tpl?

Comment: Cleared cache (actually using devel module). I have placed it in templates folder in my theme.

Comment: Which theme you are using? Any base theme or ?

Comment: no base theme...